# Very confusing solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$4y^2+z^2-x+16y-4z-20=0$

So ive been solving it in this way.
 $4(y^2-4y)+(z^2-4z)-x-20=0$

Is it possible to delete the -20 with factoring these terms $4(y^2-4y)+(z^2-4z)$ 
in this way? $4(y-2)^2-16+(z-2)^2-4-x+20=0$ ??

If the above question is correct how i could make from $-x$ to $-x^2$ at this point
$4(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2-x=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your factorization. The first line can be written as
$$x=4(y+2)^2 + (z-2)^2 - 40.$$
If it's a $+20$ instead (like how you changed it halfway through), then there is no $-40$.

As for what else there is to do - not much. There's no $x^2$ term! The equation we have is an elliptic paraboloid that opens up towards the positive $x$-axis, shifted $-40$ units on the $x$-axis, $+2$ units on the $z$-axis, and $-2$ units on the $y$-axis. Anything on the curve is a solution!